# Netgear Nighthawk R8000p Cannot Patch

Tags: router, patch

Does anyone know why Netgear's Nighthawk R8000p won't patch?  This thread goes on, and on, and on, but offers no solution.  I'm looking for someone who successfully fixed it; hopefully without the need to TFTP into my device because I don't have a clue how to do that.  I'm just a customer who expected this to be simple.

REF: https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/R8000p-can-t-update-firmware/td-p/1959938/page/2

My device has 2 issues:

1. It's config is totally lost when the power cycles on the device; a sweet feature the egg heads at Netgear left me; intentionally or haphazardly
2. It won't patch beyond version v1.4.1.50_1.3.10.  I tried a factor reset and patch, but that failed too.

Oh, before I forget, if your a Netgear guy wondering why I did not raise this issue on Netgear's site, it is because I don't like cyber bullies.  =)